# What is this home folder in my downloads folder?

Tags: filesystem

I am trying to remove or delete Acrobat 9 which isn't working properly but it isn't showing up in the Synaptic Package so I've located it in a folder called 'home' which is in my downloads folder. The home folder there is locked so I have a couple of questions.

What is that 'home' folder and why is it in the 'downloads' folder?
How can I unlock folders to delete them? I'm told that I don't have permission, but it's my computer so why?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.  I eventually managed to change ownership of that 'home' folder and deleted it. It only contained the Adobe stuff, nothing I needed.

```
sudo chown -R $USER: ~/Downloads/home
rm -r ~/Downloads/home
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete it, you'll have to sudo up.  Open up a terminal (Ctrl+t), and then ype

```
sudo -s -H
```

Navigate to the Downloads folder

```
cd /home/[your user name]/Downloads
```

Then use the rm command to remove the folder

```
rm -r Home
```

If you just wanted to unlock the folder, sudo up and navigate to the location like above, but instead of using the rm command use chown (this will also unlock all the files inside the folder for you)

```
chown -hR [your user name] home
```

That will get rid of the home folder or unlock it, whatever you prefer.  As or what it is or why it's there, I have no idea.

Comment: Hi and thanks for that. I tried changing ownership as you suggested but get 'operation not permitted' for each of the hundreds of files and to delete the Adobe folder in there seems to be impossible too as I am asked to go into each file in there.

Comment: I can't move that home folder either because it is locked.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method if you're struggling with permissions issues:

1. Make sure it's safe to remove this folder (e.g. viewing its contents to see if it contains anything other than the Acrobat stuff)
2. Use a live CD/DVD/USB with Parted Magic or other Linux distribution that gives the user full root access by default to permanently delete this unwanted folder.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
sudo rm -rf /home/matt/Download/home
```

The `-f` means force.